# How to project Lat/Lon coordinates on a panorama image?

Tags: latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, panoramas, google-street-view

I have two sets of Latitude/Longitude coordinates.

The first one is the coordinates of an equirectangular panorama picture.
The second one of a point in sight. So it is on the picture.

I need the x/y coordinates of the second point to draw it on the picture.
In javascript.

Example equirectangular panorama picture and application (using bearing and distance instead of Lat/Lon coordinates):

http://www.diy-streetview.org/data/development/20100121/streetview-playerA.html?streetview=small/001sm.jpg

Hints:
The horizon is half the hight of the image.
The camera was 2 meters above ground.
Image Direction is the middle of the image. Where it "looks to".

It's in the Netherlands, so a negative Altitude is no error. They are really below the waterline.

Skipp the camera hight and GPSAltitude when its to complicated.

A bit data:

**001sm.jpg**
GPSLatitude: 51.802104
GPSLongitude: 3.929393
GPSAltitude: 1.100000
GPS Image Direction = 260 degrees

**002sm.jpg**
GPSLatitude: 51.802082
GPSLongitude: 3.929200
GPSAltitude: -2.270000
GPS Image Direction = 265 degrees

**003sm.jpg**
GPSLatitude: 51.802082
GPSLongitude: 3.928986
GPSAltitude: -3.710000
GPS Image Direction = 275 degrees

**004sm.jpg**
GPSLatitude: 51.802104
GPSLongitude: 3.928771
GPSAltitude: -3.710000
GPS Image Direction = 270 degrees

Thanks,
Jan
janmartin AT diy-streetview DOT org